# Converting a raw number to a timestamp in Excel

Tags: excel, timestamp

I have a set of numbers ranging from 390 up to 999 in increments of 1. These numbers correspond to timestamps, so 390 corresponds to 6:30am (the 390th minute of the day is 6:30am), 391 corresponds to 6:31am, and so on. Is there a simple formula in excel that could convert these numbers to timestamps for me? I have the first column, Time ID, and I'm wanting to calculate the second column, Time.

```
Time ID Time
390 6:30:00 AM
391 6:31:00 AM
392 6:30:02 AM
```

Comment: Divide by 1440, the number of minutes in a day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data starts in Row 2:

```
=A2/(24*60)
```

or

```
=TIME(0,A2,0)
```

To force the format, wrap either of the above with `TEXT([formula], "hh:mm:ss am/pm")`

<sub>(Shamelessly stolen from the Great @ScottCraner's comments [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1143399/excel-converting-minutes-to-hours-and-minutes-in-hhmm-format))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

you can divide by 1440 and then format the cell as time